# Set hour format in schedules - AgendaDay view in FullCalendar.js

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm working a medical scheduler made in Fullcalendar.Js plugin. I'm trying to set the next visual detail:

I've got the default hour format for each row in this sample image:

[image]

Is there any format type not only shows the o'clock hour by default, but also shows the respective hour for each row? i.e. 5 pm; 5:20 pm; 5:40 pm, etc.

I need something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that effect you need to set the `slotDuration` to a smaller value, e.g.

```
slotDuration: "00:40"
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/64/

Docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotDuration/

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!